# Java: match all strings that do not end in .htm?"

Tags: java, html, regex, string-parsing

I'm parsing an HTML file in Java using regular expressions and I want to know how to match for all href="" elements that do *not* end in a `.htm` or `.html`, and, if it matches, capture the content between quotes into a group

These are the ones I've tried so far:

`href\s*[=]\s*"(.+?)(?![.]htm[l]?)"`

`href\s*[=]\s*"(.*?)(?![.]htm[l]?)"`

`href\s*[=]\s*"(?![.]htm[l]?)"`

I understand that with the first two, the entire string between quotes is being captured into the first group, including the `.htm`(`l`) if it is present.

Does anyone know how I can avoid this from happening?

Comment: Do you want to capture htm and html file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rearrange the expression, and move the negative look-ahead to before the capturing:

```
href\s*[=]\s*"(?!.+?[.]htm[l]?")(.+?)"
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/jfOEkO) is a demo.

Answer (score 1):

As a side answer, [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a very good API when dealing with html.

Using jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
for(Element link : doc.select("a")) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    if(linkHref.endsWith(".htm") || linkHref.endsWith(".html")) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is for a school assignment where I am not allowed to use any such libraries! :-(

Comment: I understand. As I said it is just a side answer for the record :) Good luck for your homework.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `.*\.(?!(htm|html)$)`

any character in any number .*  followed by a dot .  not followed by htm, htmt (?! ... )